# Add Published Web application to Setup Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have a Solution with two projects
1. WCF Service application
2. Setup project

I want to add published output of the WCF service application to some folder mentioned in Setup project at each build.
So, that when I install the msi generated by Setup project, the published output of WCF service application gets stored in some predefined folder.

Later, i want to publish the predefined folder to some IIS through other means.

Currently, i can manually publish WCF service application to some folder. But how to automate the process, so that the published app get stored in some predefined folder of setup project.